# How do I get administrator permissions on an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an Amazon account, as does my colleague.

He spun up an EC2 instance, and wants to give me admin permissions. In particular, I want to be able to start and stop the instance, open and close ports, etc.

How does he give me admin perms for the instance?

I would like to use commands like:

`ec2-authorize default -p 8000-8001`

I already have an access key and a secret key, but my colleague provided me with one. He did not, however, provide me with the X.509 CERT, and a lot of the admin commands complain that I need it. How do I get a cert?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the access and secret key with Elasticfox to do GUI based administration. If you're using command line API tools, well you really need the certs.

Otherwise use boto which use access and secret keys only.

Comment: How do I get the cert?

Comment: You can create them in your EC2 AWS account dashboard or let your colleague create/have it for you.